# Silverlight opening relative URI - works when debugging, fails when running outside VS

Tags: xml, silverlight, silverlight-3.0

My Silverlight project uses `dane.xml` file, which is located in `ProjectName.Web/Client.Bin/dane.xml`

```
private void ReadXML()
{
    WebClient client1 = new WebClient();
    client1.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(client1_DownloadStringCompleted);
    link  = new Uri("dane.xml", UriKind.Relative);
    client1.DownloadStringAsync(filePath);
}

void client1_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Error != null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Error.ToString() + "\n\nURI=" + link.ToString());
        return;
    }
    // (...)
}
```

Everything is working fine when I run it from Visual Studio (Debug or Start without debugging). But now I'd like to start it outside VS, so I ran `ProjectName.Web/ProjectNameTestPage.html` - and loading `dane.xml` file failed, with following error from MessageBox:

> Error when loading file dane.xml
>
> System.Net.WebException: An exception occurred during a WebClient request.
>   ---> System.NotSupportedException: The URI prefix is not recognized.
>   in System.Net.WebRequest.Create(Uri requestUri)
>   in System.Net.WebClient.GetWebRequest(Uri address)
>   in System.Net.WebClient.DownloadStringAsync(Uri address, Object userToken)
>   (...)
>
> URI=dane.xml

What should I do to fix that?

I've already tried setting `dane.xml` in Solution Explorer as Resource and creating `new Uri("ProjectName;component/dane.xml", UriKind.Relative);`, but it fails when running on Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. I've put my site on apache server (copy `ProjectName.web` folder and run `ProjectNameTestPage.html`) and now it works.